# ActionScript 3.0: How to create float variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, actionscript

I thought

```
var:Float = 1,0;
```

would work but it doesnt work since its already used by text. My other idea is that theres something else wrong im my program - I get error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'ac3', Frame 1, Line 28 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before 0.

witch is pointing to

```
var i = 1,0;
```

Rest of my code -

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

stop();

var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fadebgr);

timer.start();

function fadebgr(e):void
{
if(bgr.alpha <= 0) //read the last line of this post to know what is "bgr";
{
    var i = 0;
    while(i < 1)
    {
        bgr.alpha += 0,1;
        i++
    }
}

if(bgr.alpha >= 1) 
{
    var i = 1,0;
    while(i > 0)
    {
        bgr.alpha -= 0,1;
        i++
    }
}
}
```

and the only thing I hove on screen is a movieclip (default black circle), named bgr.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have used the comma instead of dot to represent the float value. B Replace the comma with dot.

The code for declaring should be like -

Var i = 1.0

Comment: In my country (Czech Republic) in numbers we write "." instead of "," :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Float` native type in flash.  You should use `Number`.   The Float you are importing has nothing to do with numbers and is a utility class for displaying text.

```
var i:Number = 1;
```

Though you are using it as an integer and flash does have a native type for that:

```
var i:int = 1;
```

However, it looks you want to fade in/out your background?   I don't see the purpose of your while loops if they only run one time.

This will step your alpha up/down by 10% every timer interval:

```
function fadebgr(e):void
{
    bgr.alpha += (bgr.alpha <= 0 ? .1 : -.1);
}
```